# Comparing Age to Date of Birth in MYSQL is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have a query that I am running and it includes checking that someones age range is within a certain range. So I added a where clause
For example:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) <= 42 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) >= 25
```

This doubles the time it takes to run my query. Is there any way I can do this and utilize my indexes as this seems to be searching every row.

I will like to speed up performance and query time

Comment: Have you tried storing the users current age as a column?

hence you could remove the call to TIMESTAMPDIFF? 

So your query can be like: `WHERE age <= 42 AND age >= 25`

Comment: Please post the complete query you started with for an alternative that will avoid calling CURDATE() twice for every row examined.  Calling CURDATE() twice in this manner is expensive use of resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for age, you don't have to calculate the age. All you need is the dates that encapsulate those ages. If I want everybody who is at least 25 today, I want everybody who is born <= 25 years ago. If I want everybody who is max 42, I want everybody who is born >= 42 years ago. That's a MUCH simpler query:

```
WHERE dob >= <42 years ago> AND dob <= <25 years ago>
```

You pre-calculate those 2 dates ONCE, and put them in the query. In PHP that would be something like:

```
$ago42 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-43 years')); // because 25-42 years is not 17 but 18 years
$ago25 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-25 years'));
```

If you index the `dob` column, that's a blazing fast query.